# How to grep a log file within a specific time period with string

Tags: linux, grep

I have a log file in this format:

```
2016-01-21 01:56:48,586 [http-nio-8320-exec-54] INFO  config.web.login  - Successful login. Username: XYZ, xxxxx
```

How do I grep this file and get only the lines where the time is between 1:50:00 and 1:56:00 and where the string `config.web.login  - Successful login. Username: XYZ` is present? I'm trying to count the number of successful logins for a certain username.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the help of awk and grep.

Try this code:

```
awk '/01:50:48/, /01:56:48/' <<FILENAME>> | grep 'Successful login. Username: XYZ,\s\+xxxxx'
```

Where /01:50:00/ is the start time and /01:56:00/ the stop time. Replace << 
FILENAME>> with the path to your log file.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are interested in the 01:50:00 to 01:56:00 time frame on only the date 2016-01-21 that is shown in your example.

Here's a solution using only grep:

```
$ egrep '^2016-01-21 01:(56:00|5[0-5]:[0-5][0-9]).*[[:blank:]]config.web.login  - Successful login. Username: XYZ,'
```

Answer (score 0):

If anybody wants to get the logs within the particular time rage, maybe you want to get the logs within 5 min you can do like the below

For dynamic time range (eg you dont know the time range but needs logs between last 5 min)

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG_FILE="./modsec.txt"
SEARCH_WORD="ModSecurity: Access denied"
START_TIME=$(date -d "5 minutes ago" "+%H:%M")
END_TIME=$(date "+%H:%M")

# using sed
sed -n "/"$START_TIME"/,/"$CURRENT_TIME"/p" "$LOG_FILE" | grep -w "$SEARCH_WORD"
```

For static time range (you know the time range)

`sed -n "/hh:mm/,/hh:mm/p" "$LOG_FILE" | grep -w "$SEARCH_WORD"`   (you can replace the time range based on your timestamp)

Comment: What question are you answering?